# How to display complex data or to change template for the first and last elements in ngFor?

Tags: angular

Similar questions are already asked, but mine is slightly different. Or I just did not find the right one?

I'm using Angular 10, and need to display complex data of parent with a list of children:

```json
    data = [
      { Name: 'n1', Items: [{ i1: '0000', i2: '000' }] },
      {
        Name: 'n2',
        Items: [
          { i1: '11', i2: '1' },
          { i1: '2', i2: '222222' },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

HTML:

```html
    <table border=1>
      <head>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
          <th colspan="2">Items</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>I1</th>
          <th>I2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <body>
          <tr *ngFor="let d of data">
            <td>{{ d.Name }}</td>
            <td colspan="2">
              <table border=1>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of d.Items">
                  <td>{{ item.i1 }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.i2 }}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Obvious problem is that width of items' cells for different data elements might have different width.

To overcome this, I'd like to avoid creating a separate table inside of 'items' cell, but use cells of the 'main' table. For examples, something like this:

```html
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let d of data">
        <tr>
          <td attr.rowspan="{{ d.Items.length }}">{{ d.Name }}</td>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of d.Items">
            <tr>
              <td>{{ item.i1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.i2 }}</td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>          
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
```

Though, I need to somehow 'hide' the first '' for every first item and '' for the very last one.

When I wrote the question and explained it well (hopefully) to myself, I believe that I can achieve the goal by modifying 'html' inside of '' for the 1st and last records by using this idea:

```html
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let d of data">
        <tr>
          <td attr.rowspan="{{ d.Items.length }}">{{ d.Name }}</td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of d.Items; let i=index">
              <ng-container *ngIf=" i !== 0 " >
                <tr>
              </ng-container>                
                <td>{{ item.i1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.i2 }}</td>
              <ng-container *ngIf=" i !== d.Items.length-1 " >
                </tr>
              </ng-container>                 
            </ng-container>          
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
```

But this code gives me an error:

> Unexpected closing tag "tr"

Please advise, how can I display complex data in such a way? Or how to hide properly some tags with-in the 'ng-container'?

Thanks!

Comment: for the first and last element u can get true false values using ngFor like this.
`*ngFor="let d of data; let first = first; let last=last;"`. angular exposes the following variables. `index`, `first`, `last`, `even`, `odd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe below is what you are trying to achieve

```html
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
            <th colspan="2">Items</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>I1</th>
            <th>I2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let d of data">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of d.Items; let first=first">
        <tr>
          <td  *ngIf='first' [attr.rowspan]='d.Items.length'>{{ d.Name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.i1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.i2 }}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the line `[attr.rowspan]='d.Items.length'`. This ensures that the table properly aligns

Below is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgzgko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Simple and readable, as it should be. Thanks a lot!